# Using overloaded methods in java Spring while configureing context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, swing

How cat I use overloaded method in context.xml file while configureing my application?
I have such code to configure main frame of my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="todo_Default" class="com.yurets_y.todo_list.components.MainFrame" init-method="init" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="size" ref="dimention"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dimention" class="java.awt.Dimension">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="200"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="300"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

and I want to use mehtod setSize(int x, int y) of class JFrame, instead of using method setSize(Dimention d). What should I do to use different veriety of overloaded methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to call setSize(int x, int y) using

> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="todo_Default" class="com.yurets_y.todo_list.components.MainFrame" init-method="init" lazy-init="true">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="todo_Default"/>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>setSize</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>300</value>
            <value>200</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but I would rather use your solution with java.awt.Dimension bean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that it should be a bit easier. but now I know how to invoke different methods from bean using your example of MethodInvokingFactoryBean